# Why dose mktime cost so much time when passing a parameter with tm_isdst is set to 1?

Tags: multithreading, mktime

I call mktime in a multi thread program, and want to transfer a string to Unix timestamp. Then I found the program's performance is so poor and the CPU idle almost down to 0%.

```
    tm tm_;
    char buf[128]= {0};
    strcpy(buf, strValue.c_str());
    strptime(buf, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm_); 
    int ts  = mktime(&tm_);
```

I use perf top to profile the program. It shows spin lock occupy most of CPU time.(Up to 80%).

When I set tm_.tm_isdst=0, then it seems no spin lock is called any more.

My question is: Why setting tm_isdst to 0 will save the calling of spin lock? I read the source code of mktime, it seems that when the tm_isdst is set to 0, it won't save any calling of localtime function where pthread_mutex_lock is called.

[mktime](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ntp/ntp-12/ntp/libntp/mktime.c.auto.html) 
[localtime](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/stdtime/localtime.c)

Comment: Did you check the value of `tm_isdst` before setting it to 0? Was it positive or negative? According to docs negative value means the information is unavailable, perhaps in such a case `mktime` tries to discover this from system settings?

Comment: tm_isdst is 1 before i set it.